# Import the icon of TabPanel from file in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I have a simple app and want to add custom icons to my TabPanels

See code

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  navlistPanel(
    tabPanel('Menu1', icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
             'Menu One',
             tags$img(src='svg/frame.svg', height='40', width='40')
             
             ),
    tabPanel('Menu2',
             icon = tags$img(src='svg/frame.svg', height='40', width='40'),
             'Menu Two')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As you can see, the tag is working well and I can see the svg image (in www/svg)

[image]

However it does not render the icon for Menu 2.

Comment: icon is a function to use icons from the Font Awesome and Glyphicons libraries and convert them into html code to display them. So it is not a placeholder for "anything" to be added in front of the menu item.

Comment: All right. using div then

Answer (score 1):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  navlistPanel(
    tabPanel('Menu1', icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
             'Menu One',
             tags$img(src='https://www.svgrepo.com/show/5840/like.svg', height='40', width='40')
             
             ),
    tabPanel(div(img(src='https://www.svgrepo.com/show/5840/like.svg', height='20', width='20'), "Menu2"),
             'Menu Two')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution is

`title = div(img(src="svg/frame.svg"), "My Title")`

Answer (score 0):

Using `shiny::img` to supply the image/icon to the `icon` parameter is sufficient. `24px` will match the size of the icon that would otherwise come from `shiny::icon()`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  navlistPanel(
    tabPanel('Menu1', icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
             'Menu One',
             tags$img(src='svg/frame.svg', height='40', width='40')
             
             ),
    tabPanel('Menu2',
             icon = img(src='svg/frame.svg', height = '24px', width = '24px'),
             'Menu Two')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```